# Return object id after file is uploaded

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a simple Django app to upload an image file using a form. I'd like to be able to use the id (primary key assigned in the model) in the view function. How can I get that primary key? I feel like I must be missing something simple.

Model:

```
class image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py:

```
def image_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # id = ??????????
            # Some other processing with id...
            return render(request, 'image_uploaded.html', context=context)
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
        return render(request, 'reader/image_form.html', {
        'form': form
})
```

forms.py

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = image
        fields = ('image', )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is:

```
instance = form.save()
id = instance.id
```

the method save of the form return instance of the model you save, more details [the-save-method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

also please read the [coding-style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/)